# Converting Jquery Toggle to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate

I am totally new to web programming. I built a slide navigation and wanted to make it slide from the left to the middle. The thing is I just found a Jquery code. I tried to look it up by searching on google but the matches didn't match to the thing I was looking for.

Here is the Code:

```
$('.nav-side .nav-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('nav-open');
})
```

I would like to know if I can translate this into Javascript because I would like to continue using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: look at [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors), [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) etc

Comment: jquery is also javascript :)

Comment: I think you should try converting it to Javascript yourself and then ask for help if what you tried doesn't work. Instead of asking for `ready to use` code.

Answer (score 2):

In pure JavaScript it should be something like this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-side .nav-toggle');
[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        element.parentNode.classList.toggle('nav-open');
        return false;
    }, false);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/r0x7zehz/

Comment: this seems to be fine, but the nav bar does not react. i linked my javascript in the html script this way: <script type="text/javascript" src="Controller.js"></script> is it not correct?

Comment: @Garzec I don't really know. It fully depends on the way how you organise the markup and JavaScript files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classList.toggle()`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nav-toggle')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('nav-open');
});
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXdooW) example.

Comment: @Garzec Can you post your html?

Comment: Sure, this is my html: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
<nav class = "nav-side">
Side Content
<a href="#" class="nav-toggle" onclick="clickHandler(this)"></a>
</nav>

<div class = "wrapper">
<p> ??? </p>
</div>

</body>

</html> How can i format the code here for a better view ?

Comment: Try putting your script tag at the bottom, just before the closing body tag (</body>). You can use [ChromDev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en) to see if the script is loading properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is pure javascript code

```
function clickHandler(dom)
{
    dom.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        dom.parentNode.classList.toggle('nav-open');
        return false;
    }, false);
}
document.querySelector('.nav-side .nav-toggle').map(clickHandler);
```

Comment: This works the way i want to have it :) But 1 question is left, on my html script i have now:     <a href="#" class="nav-toggle" onclick="clickHandler(this)"></a>                and on my javascript i have pasted in your code. But i have to click 2 times on the button to make the nav bar slide. how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your HTML

```
<a href="#" class="nav-toggle" onclick="toggleFunction(this)">Toggle</a>
```

And Here is your javascript which adds style="display:none;" when the parent style="display:block;". vice versa

```
<script>
function toggleFunction(elem){
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    if(hasClass(parent, 'nav-open')){
         parent.classList.remove('nav-open');
    }else{
        parent.className += " nav-open";
    }
}
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Edited answer. Now it does

Answer (score 1):

I just got it by writing:

```
function clickHandler(dom){
        dom.parentNode.classList.toggle('nav-open');
        return false;
}
```

But thanks everyone for the answers :)